# how to pull data from am XML file and show it on html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

here is my code(took from a old post). what I am doing wrong?

1.First one test.xml, a xml file to store data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
    <entry>
        <Date>1/01/2001</Date>
        <ProductName>milk</ProductName>
        <Quantity>10</Quantitty>
        <GrossPrice>50</GrossPrice>
        <Profit>10</Profit>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <Date>2/10/2007</Date>
        <ProductName>milk</ProductName>
        <Quantity>20</Quantitty>
        <GrossPrice>100</GrossPrice>
        <Profit>20</Profit>
      </entry>
</item>
```

2.Second one is demo.html, to show the data stored in xml file. This html has an input tag as Text and a submit button. OnClick on the submit button, it should search for the input given and show the output.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    Product Name: <input type="text" name="ProductName" id="input">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="searchXML()">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="results">
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc(dname)
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
            xhttp.send();
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        } 
        function searchXML()
        {
            xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("test.xml");
            x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ProductName");
            input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            size = input.length;
            if (input == null || input == "")
            {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Please enter a Product Name!";
                return false;
            }
            for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
                startString = ProductName.substring(0,size);
                if (startString.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase())
                {
                    date=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Date")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    product=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ProductName")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    quantity=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Quantity")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    grossprice=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("GrossPrice")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    profit=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Profit")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    divText = "<h1>The contact details are:</h1><br /><table border=1><tr><th>Date</th><th>Product</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Gross Price</th><th>Profit</th></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + product + "</td><td>" + quantity + "</td><td>" + grossprice + "</td><td>" + profit + "</td></tr>" + "</table>";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    divText = "<h2>The product does not exist.</h2>";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= divText;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error on chrome as---

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/chandan/Desktop/demo/test/test.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
demoNew.html:28 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/chandan/Desktop/demo/test/test.xml'.

However when I run this on firefox it's loading the xml file, but not showing the output, giving error on line 44 of Html..

how to fix?

Comment: please make a fiddle so that other can help here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to access a local file, and most browsers (recent Chrome for example) disable it by default.
The clean and HTML5 friendly way to do it is via a dialog box and the FileAPI

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Here is one example to perform your task: a dialog box allows you to select the xml file and display the info as you wish.

My main source is this one:
https://github.com/MounirMesselmeni/html-fileapi

Here is how to adapt the code

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>HTML5 File API</title>
</head>
<body >
  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal well">
      <legend>
        <h3>
          <div id="title">HTML5 File API</div>
        </h3>
      </legend>
      <fieldset>
          <label for="xmlFileinput"> <strong>XML File:</strong>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id="xmlFileinput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"
          accept=".xml">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      Product Name: <input type="text" name="ProductName" id="input">      
    </form>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
    <div id="results">
    </div>    
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <footer>
    <center>
      <p>&copy; Gabriel Ter-Minassian + Mounir Messelmeni 2012</p>
    </center>
  </footer>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleFiles(files) {
        // Check for the various File API support.
        if (window.FileReader) {
          // FileReader are supported.
          getAsText(files[0]);
        } else {
          alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
        }
      }

      function getAsText(fileToRead) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // Handle errors load
        reader.onload = loadHandler;
        reader.onerror = errorHandler;
        // Read file into memory as UTF-8      
        reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
      }

      function loadHandler(event) {
        var xml = event.target.result;
        //alert(xml);   
        doc=StringtoXML(xml); 
        searchXML(doc);         
      }


      function errorHandler(evt) {
        if(evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
          alert("Canno't read file !");
        }
      }

      function StringtoXML(text){
          if (window.ActiveXObject){
            var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            doc.async='false';
            doc.loadXML(text);
          } else {
            var parser=new DOMParser();
            var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
          }
          return doc;
      } 

      function searchXML(xmlDoc)
      {
          x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ProductName");
          input = document.getElementById("input").value;
          size = input.length;
          divText=""
          if (input == null || input == "")
          {
              document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Please enter a Product Name!";
              return false;
          }
          for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
          {
              startString = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              if (startString.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase())
              {
                  date=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Date")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  product=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ProductName")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  quantity=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Quantity")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  grossprice=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("GrossPrice")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  profit=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Profit")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  if (divText==="")
                  {
                    divText="<h1>The contact details are:</h1><br /><table border=1>";
                    divText+="<tr><th>Date</th><th>Product</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Gross Price</th><th>Profit</th></tr>";
                  }
                  divText += "<tr><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + product + "</td><td>" + quantity + "</td><td>" + grossprice + "</td><td>" + profit + "</td>"+"</tr>";
              }
          }
          if (divText=="")
          {
              divText = "<h2>The product does not exist.</h2>";            
          }
          else
          {
              divText+="</table>";
          }
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= divText;
      }       

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example with milk: 2 entries]
Hope that helps,

Comment: what is the best way to avoid this... As I am unable to --allow-file-access?

Comment: I don't want to display all entries of the file. In my html there is a search box, it should display only what is searched...

Comment: thank you, it really helps. but still not showing the product i searched for

Comment: which browser? be more specific

Comment: In all browser, it only returning the first entry it's getting from the table, not the others if any...

Comment: done. See the example with IE. to do another search, refresh the page  with F5.